# Python vs Ruby class methods

Tags: python, ruby

The following two Ruby and Python codes are examples of class methods. Why does python allow accessing class methods through objects but ruby doesn't ?

Python code

```
class student:
    b = 78

    @classmethod
    def foo(var):
        return var.b

z = student()
print z.foo()    # => 78
```

Ruby Code

```
class Student
  @@b = 78

  def self.foo
    @@b
  end
end

z = Student.new
puts z.foo    # => -e:20:in `<main>': undefined method `foo' for #<Student:0x007ff4f98ab9e8> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Your question boils down to "why are different languages in fact different?" Because they are different languages...?

Comment: @kindall  actually  I just want to know whether there is a particular reason or not

Comment: In ruby you can use `puts z.class.foo`

Comment: @knut  thanks got it, but what  .class  actually do ?

Comment: "How do I accomplish x in language y?" could be on-topic. Why is a language designed a certain way is not on-topic for SO, and is probably too subjective for Programmers SE.

Comment: I made an answer of my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer for the ruby side of your question: Ruby does allow accessing class methods through objects via a reader for the class:

```
class Student
  @@b = 78

  def self.foo
    @@b
  end
end

z = Student.new
puts z.class.foo
```

`z.class` returns the class of the object (in this case it is `Student`).

```
class Student
end
z = Student.new
puts z.class        #Student
puts z.class.class  #Class
```

Answer (score 0):

From Ruby doc [`Object#display`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-display):

> `display(port=$>)`
>
> Prints `obj` on the given port (default `$>`). Equivalent to:
>
> ```
>  def display(port=$>)
>    port.write self
>  end
> ```

So it just displays the receiver, which is a `Student` instance. I don't see how this is relevant to class methods.

Calling the class method `Student.display` is in fact possible:

```
z.class.display
```

Comment: my question is why am i able to access class methods through objects in python but not in ruby

Answer (score 0):

Ruby doesn't have class methods, only instance methods. In your case, `foo` is in instance method of the singleton class of `Student`.

Once you understand that there is no such thing as a class method in Ruby, only instance methods, it should be immediately obvious why calling an instance on a completely different instance cannot possibly work.